# Conflict between a tableView index and NSArray objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, indexing, nsarray, tableview, conflict

I'm implementing a TableView (class ListeExercice), showing a list of customized cells. These cells are defined in another class (class ExerciceTableCell).

In the class ListeExercice, I do create an NSArray as follow in the viewDidLoad method:

```
table1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"exo1", @"exo2", nil];
table2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10:00", @"10:00", nil];
```

Then in the same class, I do everything in order to display the cells in the table

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection(NSInteger)section
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

The problem I got happens ins the following method, basically where the code in order to display the right cell is located :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *exerciceTableIdentifier = @"ExerciceTableCell";
ExerciceTableCell *cell = (ExerciceTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:exerciceTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExerciceTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
} 

//label1 is a label from the cell defined in the ExerciceTableCell class.

cell.label1.text = [tableIntituleExercice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

The problem is that I got a conflict between these 2 lines:

```
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

and

```
cell.Label1.text = [table1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Apparently there is a conflict between the 2 "objectAtIndex". 
I do not have any warning, just an App crash, and a thread saying "Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1 ....)

Any advice on what I could do?

Comment: what do you mean with conflict?

Comment: By conflict, I mean that it seams the compiler has got a problem with the method "objectAtIndex" when I call it twice for different objects. For example, I I delete the line "cell.Label1.text = [table1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];", everything works fine, but I do not have the label of the cell filled.

"Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address 0x8)" is the full error.

Comment: Are you having two tables in your view and trying to populate the two tables using arrays table1 and table2

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, it's a memory management error. You have to retain `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: Dilip Rajkumar - I got two tables declared in the viewDidLoad section  of the view, they are not displayed. Then I want to get what's in these tables to populate different labels of the cells i'm displaying.

I'm not using ARC indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using ARC, it's a plain memory management error. You have to retain the two arrays in these lines:

```
table1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"exo1", @"exo2", nil];
table2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10:00", @"10:00", nil];
```

Otherwise, the objects will have been released before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called. It's for errors like these that you should generally always use property setters to assign values to ivars/properties. The setters care about the proper memory management for you.

Comment: You have to use the properties, too: `self.table1 = ...` is not the same as `table1 = ...`. If you don't know this, read it up again. It's one of the most important things in Objective-C.